# Xcode bug? Changing shadow opacity changes background highlight as well

Tags: xcode, highlight, shadow

I'm running Xcode version 4.4.1 and I've read that there are some issues with changing shadow settings and text highlight color automatically changing with it. I want to change the shadow for a button and I can't seem to do so without the whole button background color changing. This can probably be fixed in the code but I want to be able to do this in the xib. Any ideas how to get around this bug?

Comment: You might want to file a bug at Apple Bug Reporter, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Xcode, don't worry. It's been around for a few versions now. Simply change the background color again after setting the shadow color.